Google App Engine FLEX deployment fails due to .aspnetcore runtime version error
gcloud app deploy
Services to deploy:
descriptor: [C:\app.yaml]
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
#=============================#
#= Uploading 133 files to Google Cloud Storage            =#
#=============================#
File upload done.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error(s) encountered validating runtime. Your runtime version for aspnetcore is past End of Support. Please upgrade to the latest runtime version available.

it was yaml file error. I managed to resolve it.
